# Как сделать команду для телеграмм бота с варьирующейся частью?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Недавно увидел команду вида /task_123, где после нижнего подчёркивания идёт id таска, которое меняется в зависимости от задачи. Вот то, что я имею ввиду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я примерно представляю, как такую команду составить, но как её обрабатывать, если у неё есть постоянно меняющаяся часть, не являющаяся аргументом (как я понял). Пожалуйста, может кто разъяснить как такое сделать? Или поделиться ссылкой какой? А то в гугле что-то я ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text.startswith("/task_"))
async def task(message: types.Message):
    args = message.text.split("_")[1]
    print(args)
```

> input: /task_123

> result: 123

Но я бы сделал так, чтобы вместо `_` был пробел

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["task"])
async def task(message: types.Message):
    args = message.get_args()
    print(args)
```

> input: /task 123

> result: 123